# Open Console App In Background But Allow it To Reappear When Needed

Tags: c#-4.0, process, background, console-application, show-hide

I have this console app that another application starts.  This is what I'm playing around with to start it:

```
          ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\...\MyApp.exe";

        processStartInfo.Arguments = "a, a, \\n, d, c";
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

The idea behind this Console App, is that after it runs through these arguments, the only thing visible to the User is a SysTray Icon they can interact with.  One of the options is the ability to Show the console.  This is a two-fold question:

1. Since the Console App is started in the background, how do I get it to no longer be in the background?  Originally I was using some ShowWindow/HideWindow approach using some COM and P/Invoke, but this seems to be different.
2. When this Process code is run, the Console App briefly flashes then goes to the background.  How can I suppress this flash of the Console?  That doesn't look professional at all.

Comment: Does adding the `ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized` to the `WindowStyle` eliminate the flashing window problem?

Comment: No it doesn't.  I need it to initially run in the background anyways.  The problem though is that even with the window style being set to hidden and the Console App being built as a Windows Application, I still get a little flash of a console.  The funny thing is that the console app only seems to flash when trying to externally start it like this.